# electron-react-boilerplate: window.electron does not exist Error

Tags: electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I'm using electron-react-boilerplate v4.0.0
I've exposed this electron api from preload.js to use in renderer process.
[preload.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQwym.png)

The problem comes when trying use "window.electron.ipcRenderer.printTicket()" inside a react component.

[Hello React Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTVqw.png)

I have the Error: "window.electron does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post your code as text instead of as screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel,

Try this:-

Edit your index.tsx from something like this:-

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";


render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

to something like this:-

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    electron: any;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Now you can use window.electron anywhere in the renderer. This fixed the problem for me. You could also add this in the App.js file.

Although I have not tested it, you can do something like this too:-

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  hworld: "Hello world" // window.electron.hworld is a string ("Hello world")
});
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    electron: {
      hworld: string // Since you know window.electron.hworld is a string
    }
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```